# How can I find the ProgID of a Windows program to use in Wine?

Tags: wine

You can open documents in particular programs in Wine from the terminal using

```
wine start /ProgIDOpen <ProgID> <Document_to_open>
```

This format is necessary, since calling Wine programs in alternative ways will not open the document. e.g. the following launch the application, but do not open the document.

```
/path/to/prog.exe <Document_to_open>
wine /path/to/prog.exe <Document_to_open>
```

However, it's not obvious how to find the `<ProgID>` associated with each program. How can I find this information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ProgIDs are listed in `$WINEPREFIX/system.reg`, which by default is at `~/.wine/system.reg`. They are of the format.

```
[Software\\Classes\\FoxitReader.FDFDoc] 1382350649
```

Although there are additional semi-duplicate lines such as

```
[Software\\Classes\\FoxitReader.FDFDoc\\DefaultIcon] 1382350649
```

To list all ProgIDs, use the following command (in the terminal).

```
sed -rn 's/^\[Software\\\\Classes\\\\([^\]*)\].*/\1/p' system.reg | less
```

For those unfamiliar with `less`: to search, press <kbd>/</kbd>, type a phrase then <kbd>Enter</kbd> ; to exit, press <kbd>q</kbd>.

Comment: I'll accept my answer now, as it works fine, but if anyone has a simpler answer, please post it.

Answer (score 1):

#### This might be fairly late but since you called for simpler ways (and for future readers), this is what I found. I didn't find it out myself, credits go to this post on the [Ubuntu forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=749684&p=9793671#post9793671).

Since Windows uses drive letters for it's partitions but Linux follows another concept, Wine links your local file system to `$WINEPREFIX/dosdevices/z:` so programs installed with Wine would find your file system under drive Z: and could thereby access your files. Instead of struggling through the depths of the windows registry you can simply prepend the file path in the argument with `Z:`. So in order to open a PDF file with Foxit Reader you would merely have to execute a command like

```
wine /path/to/FoxitReader.exe Z:/path/to/whatever_file.pdf
```

If you want to put your program in the 'Open with' list in order to open files with a specific program by right clicking on them, you could create a custom desktop entry in your `/home/user/.local/share/applications` directory and append `Z:%f` to the Exec command. Sticking to the example, a desktop entry for Foxit Reader could look like this (given that `WINEPREFIX` is set to the path of your specific Wine environment):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Foxit Reader
Exec=wine "$WINEPREFIX/drive_c/path/to/FoxitReader.exe" Z:%f
Encoding=UTF-8
Icon=DBA8_FoxitReader.0
Version=1.0
Type=Application
NoDisplay=true
```

Contrary to the above-mentioned post it wasn't necessary for me to add all those quotation marks. In case it doesn't work for you, try with adding them back in (`'""Z:%f""'`).

Comment: Hi @Arno-Nymous, and thank you for contributing. I tested prepending `Z:` to the file path, and it indeed did work (+1). However, I also tested my original code, and it seems that wine now opens the file as expected with either of the two commands from my question that originally failed; there must have been some kind of update. However, it only seems to work with relative, not absolute paths, so your hint is definitely useful!